# libssh2 remote file attributes last modification time with wrong timezone

Tags: c++, linux, libssh2

I am using `libssh2` on `linux` with `C++`.

I intent to see last modification time before downloading a file from sftp.

To do that, I use this commands:

```
LIBSSH2_SFTP_ATTRIBUTES attrs;
libssh2_sftp_fstat_ex(sftp_handle, &attrs, 0);
```

I get the last modiciation time with `attrs.mtime`, which is a `long` type that gives seconds.

However, this value is with timezone GMT+0. How could I get the time with my local timezone?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

C Standard library support for timezone conversion functions is awful.
But in short you can do the following assuming that `tzname` variable is set correctly.

```
struct tm tm_utc;
gmtime_r(&attrs.mtime, &tm_utc);  // Converts from epoch time_t to utc struct.   
time_t local_time = mktime(&tm_utc);  // converts from time struct back to time_t in local time.

printf("local timezone %s, difference %ld\n", *tzname, attrs.mtime - local_time);
```

Please note that `mktime` calls tzset internally and then uses timezone information for translating time to the right timezone. `tzset` reads `TZ` environment variable and this is how system knows which timezone to use.

Comment: Thank you. But you don't consider sftp (libssh2 library), which is the core of the problem. The time variable from file attribute which is served by sftp server already comes in seconds and does not include timezone information. Do you know how could I get this?

Comment: I am not sure I understand. You wrote that attrs.mtime is GMT time and you want to translate it to *your* timezone. It does not seem to be related to sftp server.